# I'm trying to create a heatmap using plotly which would show an animation of sort of the covid affected regions, but it has some problems

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, choropleth

So below is the code, I ran to get my heatmap.

The problem is that some of the countries do not have an updated row every day so there would be some missing days before there appears a row for one of these countries. This reflects in the choropleth map where it shows the country with a case and then removes it for the days it did not have any data. I would want to keep the highlight that first appeared even if some of the days went missing but i find it difficult.

```
merg['Difference'] = np.where(merg.Country_Region == merg.Country_Region.shift(), merg.LastUpdate - merg.LastUpdate.shift(), np.nan)
```

I have created a column called difference that stores difference between dates for two rows:

```
fig = px.choropleth(maps, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="Confirmed", # Confirmed is a column of confirmed cases of maps
                    hover_name="Country_Region", # column to add to hover information
                    animation_frame = "LastUpdate", #LastUpdate is the column of dates
                    color_continuous_scale=['#0d0887', '#46039f', '#7201a8', '#9c179e', '#bd3786', '#d8576b', '#ed7953', '#fb9f3a', '#fdca26', '#f0f921'])
fig.show()
```

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using John Hopkins as your data source. They have a nice time series CSV files that has has the same number of columns (for each day since 1/22) for COVID case/death/recovery data. Here is the [link](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv) to it!